# curl sending information POST method

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to pass data from an `HTML` form `POST` using `curl`, does anyone know how to do this?
 My code: (dtda.php)

```
<?php 
// HTTP authentication 
$url = "http://siteapi.com.br:9988/api"; 
$ch = curl_init();     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "Teste:123456");  
$result = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);  
echo $result; 
?>
```

My second code HTML: (sending.html)

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="http://endereco.com.br/dtda.php" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="op" value="event"/> 
<input type="text" name="seq" value="45" />
<input type="text" name="type" value="nexttrack" />
<input type="text" name="priority" value="1" />
<input type="submit" style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px" class="button   compact" onclick="javascript:openlive()"  value="Ativar agendamento" /><p></form> <br /><br />
 </form>
```

As I pass the form data to the "endereco.com.br/dtda.php" ?

Comment: Your HTML is broken: `<p></form><br><br></form>`. You open a paragraph that's never closed, and you close your form tag TWICE. As for knowing how to do this, yes... yes we do

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish here?  Submitting an HTML form via curl doesn't really make sense--you'd more likely include POST data in the curl request and bypass the HTML entirely.  If you actually need to submit an existing form, curl isn't the right tool.  You should use a headless browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try

$url = "http://siteapi.com.br:9988/api"; 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
http_build_query(array('yourData' => $data)));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forward the posted data to another URL, you can add it like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents('php://input'));
```